# Stop fragment's functions and calls and reset inner variables

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

In my app I have an activity and a fragment.

The fragment works with a parameter "A" that is given by the activity. It has its own arrays, etc. The fragment is moving among its different functions (from a function to another) and also it makes calls to asynchronous functions to receive files, read from a database, etc.

The situation is that I want, in a concrete moment when I push a button in mi activity, send a notification from my main activity to the fragment to stop all the processing and start from the begining the process with an original parameter "B". That is, restart all the variables in the fragment, stop all the functions currently running, and all the asynchornous functions, etc, and start with the B parameter the whole process in the fragment.

My solution, that is not working is as follows:

- I have a GetRequest(request) funciton in the fragment.
- From the activity, I call this function, fixing a parameter request == B.
- In each function of the fragment, I have a condition at the begining of those functions checking if (request != null). Then, if request != null I call a function in the fragment to restart all the inner variables, and call the first function, etc. Otherwise, I continue with the code normally.

The problem is that I think this doesn't work with asynchornous functions, since some times I receive errors in variables that I reset to null and they are trying to read, and so on.

I'm sure this is not the best way to achieve this. Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: so if i understand correctly, u want to pass the paramater A to the fragment,then in fragment running the function checking in the value of parameter A?

Comment: Running the fragment with the parameter A works well in the fragment for the first time. The problem is when I change the parameter A to B. There are lots of functions running in the fragment, asynchronous functions to receive files (reads from a database), variables, arrays... how can I reset all this stuff and start again the process in the fragment with the parameter B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `LiveData` with `ViewModel` in this case

**For example:**

First create a `ViewModel` class

**YourViewModel.java:**

```
//initialize this mutableLiveData first
public MutableLiveData<String> parameterA = new MutableLiveData<>("");

private void setParameterA(String myValue){
    parameterA.setValue(myValue);
}
```

Then in **YourActivity.java**,get the `ViewModel` class

```
YourViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ... all other thing 

   viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(YourViewModel.class);
}


//then whatever the situation in activity,u want to update parameterA
private void SomeSituation() {
    //update the parameterA
    ...
    viewModel.setParameterA("Your value Here")
}
```

Then in your fragment,observe the value of parameterA

**Your Fragment:**

```
  // in onCreate() or onViewCreated()

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState); 

  //get the same viewModel
  viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(YourViewModel.class);


  viewModel.parameterA.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String parameterA) {
            // anything changes on parameterA
            // do whatever you want with the value S
        }
    });
 }
```

So by the method above,whenever having the changes of `parameterA` in activity, fragment will get the update asynchornous,then you can do whatever you want with the update value inside `onChanged()` section.

As you mention in comment:

> receive files (reads from a database), variables, arrays

`LiveData` can use for custom Model class as well,for example `MutableLiveData<List<Post>>`,so when you `setValue()` in `activity`,your fragment can get the value asynchornous in `onChanged()`.

Before using `LiveData`,you need to [Add Components to your Project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#lifecycle)

This is Android MVVM architecture,you can see the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata),,example [here](https://androidwave.com/working-with-livedata/)